# protractor can't close oauth2 popup from salesforce

Tags: angularjs, salesforce, protractor

I'm new to protractor. I'm trying to write a test for a web app that interacts with salesforce. At the start of the test, it shows an oauth2 popup for the user to authorize the app.

When I call browser.driver.close() on the popup window, it stays on screen and I get this error message:

```
Failures:

  1) get past the oauth2 should just get as far as possible, for now
   Message:
     NoSuchWindowError: no such window: target window already closed
from unknown error: web view not found
```

My test does click the final 'authorize' button in the popup. This is supposed to make the popup close itself. It works fine when I click it manually, but does not seem to work when protractor clicks it.

The oauth2 process itself seems to be working fine, because I can see the main window load data from salesforce afterwards.

I'd be happy to leave the popup there, but I then get 'element not visible' errors in the test. I think that these errors are caused by the popup being shown over the top of the main window.

I guess that the popup has some config that is incompatible with browser.driver.close(). When I try switching to the main window before calling close(), it closes fine.

The relevant part of the test spec is below. The commented out blocks show some of the experiments I have tried. None of them worked.

Does anyone out there have experience with the salesforce oath2 popup, and have any suggestions? Or know of any configuration of a window that would cause this behaviour?

```
describe('get past the oauth2', function () {

var page;

beforeEach(function () {
    page = new AngularPage();
});

it('should just get as far as possible, for now', function () {
    browser.get('http://localhost:8080/test/LocalTest.html#/templateManager');

    browser.getAllWindowHandles().then(function (handles) {

        // switch to the popup
        browser.driver.ignoreSynchronization = true;
        browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[1]);

        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('username')).click();
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('username')).sendKeys('test_user@test.com');
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('password')).sendKeys('test');
        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('Login')).click();

        browser.driver.wait(function () {
                return browser.driver.isElementPresent(by.id('oaapprove'));
            },
            10000);

        browser.driver.findElement(by.id('oaapprove')).click();

        //browser.driver.ignoreSynchronization = false;
        //browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[0]);

        browser.driver.close();

        browser.driver.switchTo().window(handles[0]);

        //browser.driver.close().then(function () {
        //
        //    //to switch to the previous window
        //    browser.switchTo().window(handles[0]);
        //
        //});
```

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out through trial and error.

The issue only occurs when I have this block:

```
beforeEach(function () {
    page = new AngularPage();
});
```

It is the combination of having the AngularPage assignment in the beforeEach.

I have tried having the assignment outside of a forEach. No error.

I have tried putting a different statement in the forEach block. No error.

But as soon as I put the assignment back in the forEach the error returns.